# ReactJS: Function to render a data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a lot of page of details, so I thought to create a function to call to render directly the data.

I have created a function:

```
export const renderDetail = Content => {
  console.log('Content ', Content);
  Content.map((content, key) => {
    return (
      <div key={key}>
        <Row>
          <Col md="8">
            <dl className="jh-entity-details">
              <dt>
                <span id={content.id}>{content.name}</span>
              </dt>
              <dd>{content.value}</dd>
            </dl>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  });
};
```

While in the page in which i would to use it:

```
// code...
 const Content = [
    {
      id: 'id',
      name: 'ID',
      value: realmId,
    },
    {
      id: 'realmId',
      name: 'Realm Id',
      value: realmName,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {renderDetail(Content)}
    </div>
  );
```

My problem is that my renderDetail receives the Content, but It is not show.

How can I fix?

Thankk you

Comment: you need to return the result of `Content.map`, e.g. `return Content.map((content, key) => {`

Comment: in `renderDetail` function, you need to return from line #3 i.e. `return Content.map(....)`

Comment: Oh ok it was simple :) thank you to both of you

Comment: I'd strongly suggest making `renderDetail` a component. It effectively is one that you have to call with weird syntax.

Comment: @Quentin So you suggest to create a class?

Comment: @Jack23 — No, a component. Which essentially means renaming the function to start with a capital letter, renaming the argument to be props, and calling it with JSX syntax. `<Detail content={Content} />` and `const Detail = props => props.content.map(...);`